# Pygame black screen. Pygame just displays a black screen when i run this on vscode

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame black screen. Pygame just displays a black screen when I run this on vscode. What am I doing wrong? My pygame is just showing a blank screen when I run this code. I have searched for solutions but haven't found anything that applies to this scenario.

```
import pygame

screen_size = [360, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
spaceship = pygame.image.load('spaceship.jpg')
bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.jpg')
bullet_y = 500
fired = False

planets = ['p_one.jpg', 'p_two.jpg', 'p_three.png']
p_index = 0
planet = pygame.image.load(planets[p_index])
planet_x = 140
move_direction = 'right'

keep_alive = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while keep_alive:
  pygame.event.get()
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] == True:
    fired = True

  if fired is True:
    bullet_y = bullet_y - 5
    if bullet_y == 50:
      fired = False
      bullet_y = 500

    screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
    screen.blit(bullet, [180, bullet_y])
    screen.blit(spaceship, [160, 500])

    if move_direction == 'right':
      planet_x = planet_x + 5
      if planet_x == 300:
        move_direction = 'left'
    else:
      planet_x = planet_x - 5
      if planet_x == 0:
        move_direction = 'right'

      screen.blit(planet, [planet_x, 50])

      if bullet_y < 80 and planet_x > 120 and planet_x < 180:
        p_index = p_index + 1
        if p_index < len(planets):
          planet = pygame.image.load(planets[p_index])
          planet_x = 10
        else:
       print('YOU WIN')
      keep_alive = False

  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be indentation issues with your code which prevent your *blit* operations from occurring unless the space bar has been pressed.

I've reformatted your code minimally to permit operation, I've created coloured squares instead of your images.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen_size = [360, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

# background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
background = pygame.Surface(screen_size)
background.fill(pygame.Color("grey"))
# spaceship = pygame.image.load('spaceship.jpg')
spaceship = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
spaceship.fill(pygame.Color("blue"))
# bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.jpg')
bullet = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
bullet.fill(pygame.Color("red"))
bullet_y = 500
fired = False

# planets = ['p_one.jpg', 'p_two.jpg', 'p_three.png']
planets = ["orange", "purple", "aqua"]
p_index = 0
# planet = pygame.image.load(planets[p_index])
planet = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
planet.fill(pygame.Color(planets[p_index]))
planet_x = 140
move_direction = 'right'

keep_alive = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while keep_alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_alive = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] == True:
        fired = True

    if fired is True:
        bullet_y = bullet_y - 5
        if bullet_y == 50:
            fired = False
            bullet_y = 500

    if move_direction == 'right':
        planet_x = planet_x + 5
        if planet_x == 300:
            move_direction = 'left'
    else:
        planet_x = planet_x - 5
        if planet_x == 0:
            move_direction = 'right'

    if bullet_y < 80 and planet_x > 120 and planet_x < 180:
        p_index = p_index + 1
        if p_index < len(planets):
            # planet = pygame.image.load(planets[p_index])
            planet.fill(pygame.Color(planets[p_index]))

            planet_x = 10
        else:
            print('YOU WIN')
            keep_alive = False
    screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
    screen.blit(bullet, [180, bullet_y])
    screen.blit(spaceship, [160, 500])
    screen.blit(planet, [planet_x, 50])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I also fixed the event handler to support a quit event, i.e. closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is caused by indentation. And I suggest you turn on the automatic code formatting function in vscode